# Error using materialize.css (0.97.7) with Aurelia CLI (current version)

Tags: javascript, materialize, aurelia

The Problem:
I am trying to get the materialize.css work with the Aurelia CLI.
But what i get is the whole materialize.js as an error output in the console
and a part of the hammerjs as well i think.

What i've done
The Aurelia cli compiles fine with the follwing lines in the aurelia.json:

```
"jquery",
{
  "name": "hammerjs",
  "path": "../node_modules/hammerjs",
  "main": "hammer",
  "deps": ["jquery"]
},
{
  "name": "materialize",
  "path": "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist",
  "main": "js/materialize",
  "deps": ["jquery", "hammerjs"],
  "resources": [
    "css/materialize.css"
  ]
},
```

Maybe i am missing something here. I thought this must be as simple as the implementation of bootstrap, but i guess i was damn wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it so far.
The problem is the implementation of the materialize.js in the dist folder.
The *.js files in there are not compatible with the aurelia build system.

Easiest way is to change the aurelia.json as followed:

```
{
  "name": "materialize",
  "path": "../node_modules/materialize-css",
  "main": "js/materialize",
  "deps": ["jquery", "hammerjs"]
},
```

Finally bind the css files for materialize.css via the cdn that is provided.
Thats the best solution i've got so far.

Any better solutions are welcome.

/edit

Seems like this is not properly working either. As soon as you try to invoke materialize functions, you get errors over errors.

Answer (score 0):

For aurelia.json I added:

```
 {
    "name": "materialize",
    "path": "../node_modules/materialize-css",
    "main": "js/materialize",
    "deps": ["jquery", "hammerjs"],
    "resources": [
        "bin/materialize.css"
    ]
}
```

And for my template I added:

```
<require from="materialize/bin/materialize.css"></require>
```